# Nodejs/Swig If then extends (Conditional Inheritance)

Tags: node.js, swig-template

I am looking for a way in Swig that if a variable is set then extend a layout.

```
 {% set AjaxLoaded = "True" %}
 {% if AjaxLoaded %}
      im ajax
 {% else %}
      {% extends 'base.html' %}
      {% block Content %}
           im not ajax
      {% endblock %}
 {% endif %}
```

For some reason swig always extends base.html

i know if php/twig they have "Conditional Inheritance"

```
 {% extends var ? "minimum.html" : "base.html" %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create conditional extends or blocks in Swig Templates.

Comment: That's a sad face... Do you have any ideas on how to achieve my goal?